# Phpmyadmin accepting only one field

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I have a problem with Phpmyadmin, i just transfered my files to ubuntu because of a coursework

whenever i add a new field to phpmyadmin
it stops  adding data
basically, its accepting only one field

and when you check the table data , it gives zero result

below are my codes

```
<!--This form links the fields to the database as well as allows inseting values to the database-->

<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "Pamplemousses_db");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$Name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Name']);
$Surname = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Surname']);





// Attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO Transport (Name,Surname) VALUES ('$Name','$Surname')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($db_connect);
header("location:Transportbooking.php?note=success");
?>


This is my html file




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Transport Booking | Pamplemousses </title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">


  <?php include("navigation_bar.html");?>
<?
error_reporting(0); 


$note=$_REQUEST['note'];
?>
    </head>

    <title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hotels.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="page-wrap">
    <?PHP if($note=='success')
    {
    echo "<div class=\"success\">Form successfully submitted!</div>";
    }
?>


  </div>


  <br/>

<form action="transport_process.php" method="post" name="Transport">


     <div id="contact-area">

  <div class="form-all">
    <ul class="form-section page-section">
      <li id="cid_1" class="form-input-wide" data-type="control_head">
        <div class="form-header-group">
          <div class="header-text httal htvam">
          <br/>
              <h2 id="header_1" class="form-header">
              Book Your Transport Here
            </h2>
            <br/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="form-line" data-type="control_fullname" id="id_3">

        <div id="cid_3" class="form-input jf-required">

          <span class="form-sub-label-container" style="vertical-align: top;">
<label class="form-sub-label" for="first_3" id="sublabel_first" style="min-height: 13px;"> Name </label><br/>
            <input class="form-textbox" type="text" size="10" name="Name" id="Name" aria-describedby="name-format" required/><br/>
          </span>

     <span class="form-sub-label-container" style="vertical-align: top;">
          <label class="form-sub-label" for="last_3" id="sublabel_last" style="min-height: 13px;"> Lastname </label><br/>
            <input class="form-textbox" type="text" size="15" name="Surname" id="Surname" aria-describedby="name-format" required/>
          </span>

      <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </ul>
  </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Three Fields But only accepting ID and Name:

[image]

When i remove everything and include only name, the database store the Name
but the moment i add surname
it stops adding data
Please help

Comment: You should learn to use prepared statements instead of string substitution.

Comment: Do you get an error when you try to insert into `surname`? What's the error?

Comment: your surname is int.. you are probably sending text data

Comment: Why are you using an `INT` datatype for the surname? Is this for a science fiction game where everyone has a number instead of a name?

Comment: @Barmar perhaps it is number.. eg : Barmar 2.0 or Barmar II (the second)?